# Django exception handling - catching ghost error from server-side

Tags: django, exception

I have a Django view that is responsible for providing raw data for graph rendering on server-side. When I run the app locally (I have Windows 10 on my machine), everything works fine. But when I run the app from the remote server (it's Ubuntu), I get an 500-error. This type of errors (when identical code is ok locally, but fails remotely), currently constitutes a serious issue for me in that on every such occasion it leads to very time-consuming - and seemingly unprofessional - process to identify and fix them. And my question is, what is the magic exception handling code snippet which would help me through the detailed exception message to client-side console.

To be more specific, consider the following (I deliberately provide the code as is):

Django view:

```
def graph_vendors_black_white(request):

    try:
        legal_entity_own_qs = get_sale_points(request.user.id)  

        list = []
        data = [x.blacknwhite_agreement_count(True) for x in legal_entity_own_qs]
        list.append({'name':u'В белую', 'data':data});
        data = [x.blacknwhite_agreement_count(False) for x in legal_entity_own_qs]
        list.append({'name':u'В чёрную', 'data':data});
        data = [x.blacknwhite_agreement_count(None) for x in legal_entity_own_qs]
        list.append({'name':u'Не выбрана опция', 'data':data});
        legal_entity_own_list = [unicode(x.short_identifier_rus) for x in legal_entity_own_qs]
        json_response = JsonResponse({'time_series':json.dumps(list,                   ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf8'),'categories':json.dumps(legal_entity_own_list,  ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf8')})
        return json_response
    except:
        user_msg, tech_msg = default_error_msg()

        return JsonResponse(user_msg + '\n ' + tech_msg, status = 500, safe = False)

def default_error_msg():
    user_msg = u'Что-то пошло не так'
    exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
    fname = os.path.split(exc_tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename)[1]
    try: 
        console_msg = exc_obj[1]
    except:
        console_msg = str(exc_obj.message)
    tech_msg = ('File - ' + fname + ' on line ' + str(exc_tb.tb_lineno) + '. \n' + \
                'Error message - ' + console_msg + '\n' + \
                'Exception type - ' + str(type(exc_obj)))             
    return user_msg, tech_msg
```

JS:

```
$.get('/graph_vendors_black_white/', function (response) 
{
   // ... some code
}).fail(function(json_result) {
    $('#black_white_container').html(json_result.responseJSON)
});
```

When I run this locally, it's perfectly ok. From remote server, it throws 500 error and most surprisingly `json_result` does not contain error message. Whereas if I put something like `a = 1/0`, I get the error message in the container instead of graph.

To sum up, the question is, what is the generic exception handling code snippet which would transmit the detailed error message to the `fail`-function response parameter NO MATTER WHAT THE ERROR IS on the server-side

Comment: You are **hiding** the actual error messages by doing a blank `except`. You must never, ever, ever do that. Catch only the errors you can deal with and let Django's own error message code handle the rest.

Comment: "let Django's own error message code handle the rest" - can you clarify how to to that programmatically ?

Comment: The problem is that I can't put breakpoints and debug the app line-by-line as in standard development process if it is run remotely, so on client-side I just get standard 500-error and I am crazy trying to figure out what exactly goes wrong.

Comment: There is no need for breakpoints. Either run as DEBUG=True, in which case Django will return its normal nice error page (which you can see in the browser dev tools since this is an Ajax request), or configure the email settings to get it to send you the errors as specified in the [error reporting docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/error-reporting/).